# set multi source video and get each duration video

Tags: javascript

I need to get duration each video, my current problem it duplicate last duration only. it skip previous duration video. ex. video1 duration is 330 seconds, video2 220seconds. console print only video2 with duplicate.

> [220, 220]

```
const fileVideo = ['video1.mp4', 'video2.mp4'];
const durationVideo = [];
const videoPlayer = document.createElement('video');

fileVideo.forEach(file => {
  videoPlayer.src = file;

  videoPlayer.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    durationVideo.push(videoPlayer.duration);
  });
});

console.log(durationVideo);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Never tried doing something like that. I think its because the old event listener reference is not updating